# SQL - Filtering by closest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table:

```
SELECT * FROM table;

Ric     Charge     Date
VOD.L   2       20180601
VOD.L   5       20181002
VOD.L   4.5     20180212
RBS.L   3       20180504
RBS.L   6       20180708
```

How could I filter, by date, such that it will return ONLY the most recent charge 
E.g.

```
Ric     Charge     Date
VOD.L   4.5     20180212
RBS.L   6       20180708
```

Comment: What's the expected result if there are 2 different rows with that date 20180212?

Comment: Now just add oracle, postgres and sybase tags and we can get limit queries for every major brand! :)

Comment: Shouldn't the closest date be `20181002` for `VOD.L`?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer simple top 1

```
select top 1 * from t order by date desc
```

As you edit question, you can use co-related subquery byt your sample output is wrong

```
select * from t
where t.date in (select max(t1.date) from t t1
                                where t1.Ric=t.Ric
                 )
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab802356f62b8a87b3b807532178da9a)

```
Ric     Charge  Date
VOD.L   5.000   02/10/2018 00:00:00
RBS.L   6.000   08/07/2018 00:00:
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table)
```

does what you ask(in multiple DB too)..

Date is a keyword in SQL and makes for a poor column name. If you can, change it now. If you can't, you might need to quote it according to the database you have

Comment: According to ANSI SQL `date` is even a _reserved_ word, not just a keyword!

Comment: Indeed.. That's probably what I meant. Shall be more specific next time

Answer (score 0):

Order by the date and then use `LIMIT 1` to only get one record.

```
SELECT *
       FROM table
       ORDER BY date DESC
       LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A self left join with an inequality would work:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
 table t1
 LEFT JOIN table t2 ON
t1.date < t2.date
WHERE
t2.date IS NULL
GROUP BY
t1.Ric
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `row_number()` with ties clause :

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by ric order by date desc);
```

If the date has ties then you can use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function such as `ROW_NUMBER` to create a windowed order number, then you can extract only the record with row number = 1 (the latest date):

```
declare @tmp table (Ric varchar(50), Charge numeric(10,3), [Date] Date)
insert into @tmp values
 ('VOD.L', 2  , '20180601')
,('VOD.L', 5  , '20181002')
,('VOD.L', 4.5, '20180212')
,('RBS.L', 3  , '20180504')
,('RBS.L', 6  , '20180708')

select t.Ric, t.Charge, t.[Date] 
from (
    select ric, 
        Charge,
        row_number() over (partition by ric order by [Date] desc) as rn,
        [Date]
    from @tmp
 ) t where rn = 1
```

Result:

[image]

*From your question it is not clear what sholud happen when there are more rows with the same Ric/date values*

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use not exists.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA AS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM TableA AS A2
                   WHERE A.Ric = A2.Ric
                     AND A2.Date > A.Date )
```